# For Loop Stuck (.C)

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
int ASCII[20] = { 92, 110, 92, 116, 92, 118, 92, 98, 92, 114, 92, 102, 92, 92, 92, 39, 92, 34, 92, 0 };

char *Constants[] = { '\n', '\t', '\v', '\b', '\r', '\f', '\\', '\'', '\"', '\0' };

int Decimal[8] = { 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 };

int Binary[8] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

int val;



for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    val = ASCII[i];
    val++;  //calculations were one off, so countered mis-calculations with this


    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){

        if (val > Decimal[i]){
            val -= Decimal[i];
            Binary[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){

        printf("%d", Binary[i]);
    }
    if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0){
        printf("%\n");
    }
}
```

I'm relatively new to C, and I'm trying to create a simple program that converts decimals (constants) to binary values. The loop, however, seems to get stuck after the first iteration like so:

```
0101110001111110
0111111001111110
0111111001111110
0111111001111110
0111111001111110
0111111001111110
0111111001111110
0111111001111110
0111111101111111
0111111101111111
```

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: source code incomplete.

Comment: could you clarify, maybe?

Comment: Did you intend the last `printf` statement to be this `printf("\n");` ?

Comment: `char *Constants[] = { '\n', '\t', '\v', '\b', '\r', '\f', '\\', '\'', '\"', '\0' };` is an error and should not compile.  Turn up your compiler warnings if you are not getting anything here.

Comment: The "getting stuck" is because you do not reset `Binary` to zeroes for the next loop iteration. It retains its old value. One way to fix this would be to add `else Binary[i] = 0;` after `Binary[i] = 1; }`

Answer (score 3):

Your variable `i` inside the bigger for loop and the other `i`'s inside the smaller loops are being confused!!

change , use different variables

**EDIT** :
As David mentioned in the comment bellow : you should also re-initialize your `Binary` after finishing using them:

```
for ( j = 0; j < 8; j++){

        printf("%d", Binary[j]);
        Binary[j] = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Also, you want to initialize `binary` inside the loop, not outside it. Otherwise, you'll never set any of the entries back to zero.

Comment: That fixed it (along with the extra comment added) Thank You!

Comment: His use of `i` is correct in all places. Agree that it's confusing, but he never used an inner `i` when he needed the outer `i`.

Comment: I realized, the original answer itself didn't change any of the outputs.